# can not deploy business network after undeploying same business network using composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have undeployed business network using command:

composer network undeploy -n supplychain-network -p hlfv1 -i admin -s adminpw

Received response as  :
"
✔ Undeploying business network definition. This may take some seconds...

Command succeeded
"

Now, I am trying to deploying same business network using command as :

composer network deploy --archiveFile supplychain-network.bna  -p hlfv1 -i admin -s adminpw

Received error as :

"

Error: Chaincode exists supplychain-network

Command failed

"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of Hyperledger fabric. It doesn't provide any way to remove deployed chaincode. This is documented as a limitation at
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/composer.network.undeploy.html